# AdMob Consent form is not showing

Tags: java, android, admob

I've integrate AdMob Consent SDK successfully on one of my apps, but once I try to integrate it again on another app, it is not showing the form and showing this line in the LogCat:

> I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(3)] "The key "viewport-fit" is not
>   recognized and ignored.", source:
>   file:///android_asset/consentform.html (3)

Please help me!

Comment: This error is not the cause of the ConsentForm not showing up, it is just an info. For the real cause, log the error description and look at it in the logcat

Comment: Checkout this link with answer: [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59108595/instagram-links-in-native-webview-on-marshmallow/64686942#64686942)